# UPDATED: AppleScript: Progress bar displaying too many files

Tags: applescript, progress-bar

Ok, so I've figured out how to grab the file count through the `find` command in `do shell script`, and how to incorporate it into the AppleScript progress display. HOWEVER...

**New Problem**

When I use the following `find` shell command, it returns the appropriate number of files in the directory (in this case, 2)

```
set mlvCount to do shell script "find /Volumes/EOS_DIGITAL/DCIM/**/*.MLV -iname *.MLV | wc -l"
display dialog mlvCount
```

However, when I try to incorporate this with the progress display, all of a sudden the script is telling me that there are 8 files being transferred.

Here's the script I'm working with:

```
--> Import Video
            
if button returned of result = "VIDEO" then 

display dialog "What video files are you importing?" with icon note buttons {"Magic Lantern Raw", "Other"}
                
if button returned of result = "Magic Lantern Raw" then
                    
display dialog "Remounting EOS DIGITAL as read only" with icon note buttons {"OK"}
                    
    set driveName1 to "EOS_DIGITAL"
                    
    set driveInfo1 to do shell script "diskutil list | grep \"" & driveName1 & "\""
                    
    set driveID1 to last word of driveInfo1
                    
    do shell script "diskutil unmount " & driveID1 & ""
                    
    do shell script "diskutil mount readOnly " & driveID1 & ""
                    
    set mlvCount to do shell script "find /Volumes/EOS_DIGITAL/DCIM/**/*.MLV -iname *.MLV | wc -l"
                    
                    ----> Progress bar
                    
                    -- UPDATE INITIAL PROGRESS INFO
                    
                    set fileCount1 to length of mlvCount
                    set progress total steps to fileCount1
                    set progress completed steps to 0
                    set progress description to "Transfering MLV files..."
                    set progress additional description to "Preparing to transfer."
                    
                    repeat with a from 1 to length of mlvCount
                        
                        -- UPDATE THE PROGRESS DETAIL
                        
                        set progress additional description to "Transfering file " & a & " of " & fileCount1
                        
                        -- TRANSFER FILES
                        
                        do shell script " rsync -av --progress /Volumes/EOS_DIGITAL/DCIM/**/*.MLV" & space & loc & captureDate & "/_CAPTURE/_VIDEO/_MLV/"
                        
                        -- INCREMENT THE PROGRESS
                        
                        set progress completed steps to a
                        
                        -- Pause for demonstration so progress is seen
                        
                        delay 1
                        
                    end repeat
                    
                    
                    -- RESET PROGRESS INFO
                    
                    set progress total steps to 0
                    set progress completed steps to 0
                    set progress description to ""
                    set progress additional description to ""
                    
                    
                    ----> Progress bar end
                    
                    display dialog "Transfer complete. Ejecting " & quoted form of driveName1 & "" with icon note buttons {"OK"}
                    
                    do shell script "diskutil unmount " & driveName1 & ""
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

////////////////////

**Original Post**

this is my second question on here. Had great luck with the first one so here goes.

**The overview:**

I'm a documentary filmmaker currently building an AppleScript application to speed up my workflow that creates capture directories and transfers raw video and audio files automatically to those capture folders.

The application is essentially automating a D.I.T. (digital imaging technician).

Most of the heavy lifting (i.e. the transferring of files from capture cards to capture directory) is done with rsync through shell scripts.

**The problem:**

I want to include a visual progress bar showing how many files have been transferred against how many are remaining. I'm transferring between 250 - 750gb of footage for each shoot day so a progress bar will be needed.

I know AppleScript has a built in progress bar command, however I can't figure out how to make this reference the "do shell script" commands. I also need the progress bars to display the progress of the transferred files, not the progress of the script as a whole.

**The script:**

Here's a snippet of the script I'm working with that covers the transferring of camera footage:

```
display dialog "What files are you importing to the directory " & quoted form of captureDate & "?" with icon note buttons {"VIDEO", "AUDIO", "STILLS"}
            
--> Import Video
            
if button returned of result = "VIDEO" then display dialog "What video files are you importing?" with icon note buttons {"Magic Lantern Raw", "Other"}
                
    if button returned of result = "Magic Lantern Raw" then
                    
    display dialog "Remounting EOS DIGITAL as read only" with icon note buttons {"OK"}
                    
    set driveName1 to "EOS_DIGITAL"
                    
    set driveInfo1 to do shell script "diskutil list | grep \"" & driveName1 & "\""
                    
    set driveID1 to last word of driveInfo1
                    
    do shell script "diskutil unmount " & driveID1 & ""
                    
    do shell script "diskutil mount readOnly " & driveID1 & ""
                    
    do shell script " rsync -av --progress /Volumes/EOS_DIGITAL/DCIM/100EOS5D/*.MLV" & quoted form of loc & "/" & quoted form of captureDate & "/_CAPTURE/_VIDEO/_MLV"
                    
                    ----> Progress bar
                    
                    
                    
                    ----> Progress bar end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I’m not seeing how you plan to match up the individual files with the `rsync` progress, but the `find | wc` shell script is returning text consisting of the number of lines ("2"), prefixed with (7) leading spaces, for a total length of 8.

Comment: @red_menace thanks for the reply. I’m just using the ```rsync -av``` instead of the shell command ```cp``` as I’ve found it to be faster for copying these files. The ```—progress``` command in the ```rsync``` line is just a holdover from when I would copy those files in terminal. It doesn’t really need to be there, I just c/p’d the original script from my notes.

Do you have an idea of how I can have the ```find``` command only return the number of lines, i.e. files on volume, rather than including the leading spaces as you’ve mentioned?

Comment: You can just coerce the string to a number, for example `set mlvCount to (mlvCount as integer)`, but you would still need to use something from rsync instead of using the number for a progress.